# Mapping $N$ objects onto $\sqrt{N} \times \sqrt{N}$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, optimization

I have $N$ objects $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_N \}$, and I know the distances between them in a distance matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$.
$d_{ij} \in D$ describes the distance between $a_i$ and $a_j$.

I chose $N$ in such a way that the square root of $N$ is a whole number, $\sqrt{N} \in \mathbb{N}$. Other values for $N$ are not considered.

How can I map the $N$ objects onto a $\sqrt{N} \times \sqrt{N}$ matrix? I want to keep objects which have a low distance close to each other on the matrix.

Which algorithms exist for this task?

The final matrix should have the following form:

A = $ \begin{bmatrix}
a_9 & a_3 & a_2 \\
a_4 & a_6 & a_7 \\
a_1 & a_5 & c_8 
\end{bmatrix}  $

E.g., $a_9$ and $a_3$ are close on the matrix because the distance between $a_9$ and $a_3$ is smaller than the distance between $a_9$ and $a_7$.

I found the "linear sum assignment", but as far as I understand it, it's not really applicable here, since I cannot define a distance from the objects to the matrix.
I only have the distances between the objects.

Edit: Each spot on the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{\sqrt{N} \times \sqrt{N}}$ matrix can only be taken once.

Comment: Okay fair, but I mean that each spot on the $\sqrt{N} \times \sqrt{N}$ matrix can only be taken once. So I have 16 objects, I know all the distances across each other, and I want to map them on a $4 \times 4$ matrix. Each spot on the matrix can only be taken once.

Comment: It's just not defined then. I only use $N$ such as $\sqrt{N} \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You definitely should mention this in the beginning of your post.

Comment: You need to define an error function of the arrangement of the numbers that you minimize over the arrangements.  There are statistics that compare two orderings of things.  You could compare the list of your distances to the list of distances between locations in the matrix.  The second will have many matches but seems to capture what you are looking for.  Now minimize the error function.  This is a combinatorial minimization problem, which are typically hard because changes in one area can affect what you ought to do somewhere far away.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It depends on your "distance" it is really subjective

You have two options: (But you need an ordering of your elements so it works only in dimension $1$)

- You make squares that are bigger and bigger (an illustrative example is better):
  $$\begin{pmatrix}1&4 &5
  \\2 &3 &6\\
  9&8&7&\vdots\\
  10 &\cdots & \cdots & \vdots\end{pmatrix}$$
  You know you are in the side of the $i^th$ square if you have  $(i-1)^2 < k \leq i^2 $
- You use antidiagonals:
  $$\begin{pmatrix}1&3 &4&10
  \\2 &5 &9&11\\
  6&8&12&\\
  7 &\cdots & \cdots & \vdots\end{pmatrix}$$
  You know you are in the $i^th$ anti diagonal if you have  $\frac{i(i-1)}{2} < k \leq \frac{i(i+1)}{2} $

If you don't have an ordering compatible with your distance, it is impossible, just consider $a_i =e_i$ the canonical $i^{th}$ vector of your basis. You have $\forall i\neq j \|e_i-e_j\| = \sqrt{2}$ you can't sort them!

Comment: Ah sorry! I clarified my question. I do not mean to map the actual integers $1, ..., N$ and their respective squares onto the matrix. Just "random" objects.

Comment: I answered you, without an ordering compatible with distance it is impossible: take elements of the canonical basis in $\mathbb{R}^N$  you'll see it cannot work

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: I need to define an order in the sense of $a_i > a_j$ between the elements for this to work?

Comment: maybe you could have some other lighter constraint, but you need to have something like that

Answer (score 0):

Comments too long for a comment.

I doubt that there's an algorithm for this. You might be able to do reasonably will with some heuristics. You need to think more about your data before you can do that.

Do the "distances" between the objects satisfy the triangle inequality, or are they essentially arbitrary?

You might sort the objects with some measure of centrality (perhaps the sum of the distances to all the other objects, or some monotone function of those distances), then put the most central object at the center of the matrix and spiral out for the rest.

Edit in response to comment

> Really? Seems like such a basic problem -- would have imagined that
> someone had already tried to solve this. But thanks for your input!
> Yes, they satisfy the triangle inequality. It's a metric in the
> mathematical sense.

I think what makes this nonstandard is the need to place the objects in a matrix. If more general planar positions are allowed there may well be algorithms - perhaps something like positioning them in $n^2-1$ dimensional space honoring the distances correctly and then looking for plane projections that preserve "centrality".

Comment: Really? Seems like such a basic problem -- would have imagined that someone had already tried to solve this. But thanks for your input!

Yes, they satisfy the triangle inequality. It's a metric in the mathematical sense.